# Añadir un registro en un comboBox cargado con DataSources

Tags: c#

Me gustaría cargar un elemento mas a este comboBox pero no me deja porque me da el error que no se puede hacer nada si se ha cargado con DataSource. Os pego el código:

```
var dtRaiz = new DataTable();
dtRaiz = objPlantilla.ObtenerListadoRaiz(1);
idRaiz.DataSource = dtRaiz;
idRaiz.ValueMember = "idRaiz";
idRaiz.DisplayMember = "Nombre".ToString().Trim();
idRaiz.Items.Add(new ListViewItem("- Seleccione -", 0));
```

Gracias

Comment: Ya hiciste varias preguntas sobre este tema, y me parece que te vendria mucho mejor entender que es tener un control enlazado a un datasource... Cuando lo enlazas, todo lo que pasa, pasa en el datasource, no en el control en si. De ahi todos tus problemas. si vacias tu source, se vacia tu control. Si agregas un elemento al source, se agrega al control. Controlas el "control" por medio del source.. de esa forma, es mas limpio y claro el codigo.

Comment: Truco: añade - Seleccione - a tu dtRaiz ...

Comment: Para complementar lo que ya te dijeron, estas programando como se hacía hace 20 años. 1) Winforms-> WPF -> UWP -> MAUI?? mira cuantas tecnologías atrás estas 2) Setear controles con datatables y editar el control para acceder a los elementos, son técnicas obsoletas. Tienes que separar la UI de los datos, esto se hace con Bindings y vas a ver como tu código disminuye notablemente.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una lista del tipo BindingList (también puede que sirva ObservableCollection). Este tipo de listas avisan cuando hay cambios al componente y lo actualizan.

```
BindingList<Algo> lista;
public Form1()
{
    lista = GetItems();
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox1.DataSource = lista;
}
```

De esta manera tienes una BindingList que está "enlazada" al DataSource de un Combobox, grilla o cualquier elemento que tenga DataSource.

Para actualizar los datos solo hay que editar la lista (agregar, eliminar, etc)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //agregamos un objeto a la lista, y el combobox se actualiza automaticamente
    lista.Add(new Algo());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo he arreglado utilizando esta línea de comandos que es muy simple

```
dtPlantilla.Rows.Add(new object[] { 0, "- Seleccione -" });
```

Gracias a tod@s